# Wrong use \@nil or \if \ifx?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

I tried to construct a macro named `mlist` which has two usages:

```
\mlist{...} will redefine the content of \clist
\mlist+{...} will apppend something to \clist
```

And my try with the following codes fails. What's wrong with my codes?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\long\def\mlist#1#2{
  \if#1+\relax \edef\clist{\clist,#2}%append #2 to \clist
  \else
    \ifx\@nil#2
    \def\clist{#1}#2 %redefine \clist
    \else
    \mlist#1\@nil
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\clist{}
\mlist{cc}\clist\par% "cc" expected
\mlist+{dd}\clist\par   % "cc,dd" expected
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are comma list utilities in `expl3` if you are looking for packaged solutions.

Comment: @Henri Menke Thank you for your suggestion. I'd like to make a solution of tex version to figure out what's wrong with my codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\mlist` macro has two arguments and with `\mlist{cc}\clist`, `#1` is `cc` whereas `#2` is `\clist`. This is definitely not what you want.

You want `\@ifnextchar` instead, which looks ahead for the next token and allows you to make a choice depending on what's found.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mlist}{\@ifnextchar+{\mlist@add}{\mlist@def}}
\newcommand{\mlist@def}[1]{\def\clist{#1}}
\newcommand{\mlist@add}[2]{% #1 is +, discard it
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\clist\expandafter{\clist,#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\clist{}
\mlist{cc}\clist\par% "cc" expected
\mlist+{dd}\clist\par   % "cc,dd" expected

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to prepend, the strategy could be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mlist}{\@ifnextchar+{\mlist@add}{\mlist@def}}
\newcommand{\mlist@def}[1]{\def\clist{#1}}
\newcommand{\mlist@add}[2]{% #1 is +, ignore it
  \expandafter\mlist@prepend\expandafter{\clist}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\mlist@prepend}[2]{\def\clist{#2,#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\clist{}
\mlist{cc}\clist\par % "cc" expected
\mlist+{dd}\clist\par   % "dd,cc" expected

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Where does your code get wrong?

In your first call `\mlist{cc}\clist` you have `cc` as `#1` and `\clist` as `#2`. This is already quite dangerous, because you can't know what comes along after `\mlist{...}`. Anyway, your `\if#1+` test turns out to be true, because it is

```
\if cc+
```

and so you get

```
+\relax\edef\clist{\clist,\clist}
```

which is something you don't want, do you? If we reverse as `\if+#1\relax` the test would turn out false and so the `\else` branch is taken, so you obtain

```
\ifx\@nil\clist\def\clist{cc}\clist\else\mlist#1\@nil\fi\fi
```

(the final `\fi` will be removed later by macro expansion). This test returns false, so you get

```
\mlist cc\@nil\fi\fi
```

Note that you have lost the braces. So let's try and fix by adding those braces. Now you get

```
\if+cc\relax\edef\clist{\clist,\@nil}\else\ifx\@nil\@nil\def\clist{cc}\@nil\else\mlist{cc}\@nil\fi\fi\fi\fi
```

(I also removed the spurious spaces). The first test is false, so you get

```
\ifx\@nil\@nil\def\clist{cc}\@nil\else\mlist{cc}\@nil\fi\fi\fi\fi
```

This test is true and everything that remains gets ignored.

Now let's examine the second call, namely

```
\mlist+{dd}
```

Here `#1` is `+` and `#2` is `dd`, so (with the already mentioned fixes) you get

```
\if++\relax\edef\clist{\clist,dd}\else...\fi
```

The part after `\else` is irrelevant, because the test turns out to be true.

So it should be

```
\long\def\mlist#1#2{%
  \if#1+\relax \edef\clist{\clist,#2}%append #2 to \clist
  \else
    \ifx\@nil#2%
    \def\clist{#1}#2%redefine \clist
    \else
    \mlist{#1}\@nil
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

but it's *not* the best approach. Please, observe carefully the position of the `%` characters.

#### A possibly better approach

I define `\mlist` with an optional argument (for managing more lists) and “embellishments”. See the examples, but essentially

```
\mlist<{a}
\mlist>{b}
```

respectively append or prepend to the list.

I also add code for extracting items from the lists and to count their length.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mlist}{ O{default} e{<>} }
 {
  \clist_if_exist:cF { l_lyl_mlist_#1_clist } { \clist_new:c { l_lyl_mlist_#1_clist } }
  \lyl_mlist_append:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mlistitem}{ O{default} m }
 {
  \clist_item:cn { l_lyl_mlist_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mlistcount}{ m }
 {
  \clist_count:c { l_lyl_mlist_#1_clist }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mlistprint}{ O{default} }
 {
  \clist_use:cn { l_lyl_mlist_#1_clist } { , }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lyl_mlist_append:nnn
 {
  \clist_put_left:cx { l_lyl_mlist_#1_clist }
   {
    \tl_if_novalue:nF { #2 } { \exp_not:n { #2 } }
   }
  \clist_put_right:cx { l_lyl_mlist_#1_clist }
   {
    \tl_if_novalue:nF { #3 } { \exp_not:n { #3 } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mlist>{cc}

\mlistprint % "cc" expected

\mlist<{bb}

\mlistprint % "bb,cc" expected

\mlist>{dd}

\mlistprint % "bb,cc,dd" expected

\mlist<{a}>{e}

\mlistprint % "a,bb,cc,dd,e" expected

\mlistcount{default} % 5 expected

\mlistitem{4} % "dd" expected

\mlist[new]

\mlist[new]<{xyz}
\mlist[new]>{abc}

\mlistprint[new] % "xyz,abc" expected

\mlistcount{new} % 2 expected

\mlistitem[new]{1} % "xyz" expected

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution and the explanation of wrong argument use in my code!! May I ask what's wrong with `\if#1+\relax` and `\ifx\@nil#2` in my code?

Comment: @lyl Essentially, everything is wrong from the outset. In the specific case, you're doing `\ifx\@nil\clist`; yes, you're trying to reinsert `#2`, but you lose braces in the meantime. The errors come from not removing `\fi` or `\else`.

Comment: And, if the new contents added to `\clist` have to be placed before the original content, I mean `{#2,\clist}` rather than `{\clist,#2}` -- I know `\preto` from etoolbox may be a way -- I wonder(prefer） if there is a solution by TeX itself.

Comment: @lyl I added an analysis of your code and how to prepend the items.

Comment: @ egreg Wonderful analysis. I really love this analysis. Thank you so much once more. And one poit, it seems that `\if+#1` is better than `\if#1+`.  I find `\mlist{#1}\@nil` leads to the lost of `\clist` which causes `\mlist{cc}\clist` no typeset. Am I right?

Comment: @lyl As I said, it's not the best approach, that is one of the reasons. I'll add my approach.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do your task only using TeX primitives:

```
\def\mlist {\futurelet\next\mlistA}
\def\mlistA {\ifx\next+\expandafter\mlistB \else\expandafter\mlistC \fi}
\def\mlistB +#1{\expandafter\def\expandafter\clist\expandafter{\clist,#1}}
\def\mlistC #1{\def\clist{#1}}
\def\clist{}

% test:
\mlist{cc}\clist\par% "cc" expected
\mlist+{dd}\clist\par   % "cc,dd" expected
```

Comment: This is a absolutely new idea for me. Thank you so much @wipet!!